# VS 2017 Python/Django Template- CSS doesn't work but inline styling does

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am working on a template generated from VS 2017 Community for Python/Django web application. 
I can't seem to get the CSS to work.
I looked at the page source and it is referencing the correct style sheet.I
adding a class (class="test") to to h4 in the .html file so that I can target it through the CSS

in the site.css I have .test{
`color: red;'
}

background, I started by trying to add a "tooltip" to this sheet. When that didn't work I went back to a simple manipulation just to see if I could get that to work.

Please let me know if you need other code snippets!
other aspects of the code work as expected it's just styling that is giving me fits.

Pretty new at this so please be just a little forgiving! :)

I wonder if maybe classes and id's from a template are not influenced by site.cs?

Turns out, there is a difference between hitting refresh in the browser and ctrl + "r". Ctrl + "r" refreshed the page (without cache i'm guessing) and the changes I made were displayed.
I added a custom.css file to the "content" folder under "app" folder.
I then added a link to that sheet in the "layout.html" file

I can see my changes now.

Might be a beginner mistake but at least I can move forward now.

Comment: Is your css file created already in a different folder?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this. "control" + "r" helped.
all my CSS seems to be working now.
Thanks fo responding Arturo.